# Including settings in to module class

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Im my module.config.php file got following excerpt:

```
return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'Util\Dao\Factory' => 'modelFactory',
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'modelFactory' => function($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
                return new \Util\Dao\Factory($dbAdapter);
            },
        )
    ),
    'doctrine' => array(
        'driver' => array(
            'application_entities' => array(
                'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
                'cache' => 'array',
                'paths' => array(
                    __DIR__ . '/../src/Application/Model'
                ),
            ),
            'orm_default' => array(
                'drivers' => array(
                    'Application\Model' => 'application_entities'
                )
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

How do i put the block "doctrine" in module class?

Comment: you Donot need Doctrine Settings in MODULE file of any Module

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is actually fairly simple. Probably your Module class has the method `getConfig()`. That method usually loads `moduleName/config/module.config.php`.

So in whatever function you are, simply call the `getConfig()`-method. This is pure and basic php ;)

```
//Module class
public function doSomethingAwesome() {
    $moduleConfig   = $this->getConfig();
    $doctrineConfig = isset($moduleConfig['doctrine'])
                        ? $moduleConfig['doctrine']
                        : array('doctrine-config-not-initialized');
}
```

However you need to notice that this only includes your Modules config. If you need to gain access to the merged configuration, you'll need to do that in the `onBootstrap()`-method. Which would be done like this:

```
//Module class
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    $application   = $mvcEvent->getApplication();
    $serviceLocator = $application->getServiceLocator();
    $mergedConfig   = $serviceLocator->get('config');
    $doctrineConfig = isset($mergedConfig['doctrine']) 
                        ? $mergedConfig['doctrine'] 
                        : array('doctrine-config-not-initialized');
}
```

This works similar if you're attaching to some events...